# Gmail API authentication with given user ID

Tags: javascript, html, api, authentication, gmail-api

Do we have a way to manually enter email id and password for the authentication in gmail api and avoid the google popup that is given by default. 
I want the user to enter the email id and password and i want to pass it to the auth. I cant find a way to do that.

the code i am using (given in gmail docs)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Gmail API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
      var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listLabels();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
       * are found an appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listLabels() {
        gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
          'userId': 'me'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var labels = response.result.labels;
          appendPre('Labels:');

          if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
              var label = labels[i];
              appendPre(label.name)
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No Labels found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: You could use a Service Account, but it wouldn't log in with the credentials of each user. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i am building an email client. Though i would provide an option to signin by google but i would also like the person to be able to enter his gmail id and pass and log in

Comment: what my goal here is that i want to make a custom ui and then ask  the user to login through my ui rather than the google popup thingy.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is mandatory, you can get the access using 2 ways

1. Create the credential.json with required details like token and other it will create a project in your google cloud account. if it related to any organisation keep in mind that you need to have permissions to create a project in google cloud platform. if it belongs individual you can get easily.

reference: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js -- js
reference: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python -- python

for other languages hit on link and select from there
2. either get the service account with required permission

Comment: Thank you for your response but What I want to do is provide the user a custom built UI to enter their email and password and then log them in. I am trying to avoid the popup we get on clicking the authorise button given by default.